# JDB Java debugger - how can I set verbose option to see why my app is crashing?

Tags: java, android, debugging, adb, jdb

I'm trying to debug some Android app with JDB Java debugger.
Here are my steps:

1. `adb shell am start -D com.appname.global.android/.MainActivity`
2. `adb jdwp`
3. `adb forward tcp:8700 jdwp:<NEW_PORT>`
4. Add `stop at com.appname.global.android.MainActivity:79` line to the C:\Users\UserName\jdb.ini file.
5. `"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17.0.2\bin\jdb.exe" -connect com.sun.jdi.SocketAttach:hostname=localhost,port=8700`

So when I execute command from step 5, my app is resuming and I hit a breakpoint in JDB (in the "onCreate" method in my app). But after few seconds my app is crashing without even telling me what is wrong. Only message I get is this:

```
main[1]
main[1]
The application has been disconnected
```

So I would like to pass an verbose option to this command.
In the help message it looks like this:

```
options forwarded to debuggee process:
-v -verbose[:class|gc|jni]
                  turn on verbose mode
```

But I can't figure out **how to pass verbose option properly**.
Can you tell me how can I do it? Or maybe there is a better way of figuring out what is wrong with my app?

Comment: So you don't get any logcat messages? Does your app use native libraries (.so files)? If a native library is crashing your app jdb won't be very helpful. I would add extra logcat logging to identify in which code part the problem is located in.

Comment: Yeah, my app is using some .so native libraries.
Ok, I'll try with logcat.

Comment: Simply connect `gdb` to your `jdb` session and take a look at what happens at the dark side of native code: https://www.owsiak.org/jni-debugging-extreme-way/